Изменение высоты TextFormField
Я пытаюсь заставить TextFormField widget менять свои размеры в зависимости от размеров экрана в данный момент.
Я обернул TextFormField в ConstrainedBox, который изменяет ограничения высоты до нужного мне значения. В TextFormField widget я определяю поле contentPadding паддингом с большим значением по вертикали, что вызывает сразу две проблемы:

Если Я буду использовать конечные значения в contentPadding, большие нужной мне высоты, TextFormField визуально изменяет свои размеры под нужны, однако, если я использую double.infinity (который лично мне кажется более подходящим в данном сценарии), flutter выкидывает следующую ошибку:

[ERROR:flutter/flow/layers/transform_layer.cc(23)] TransformLayer is constructed with an invalid matrix.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a pointer data packet:
'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart': Failed assertion: line 1636 pos 18:
'transformed == position - offset': is not true.


Даже если я буду использовать конечные значения для contentPadding, пока TextFormField рисуется правильно, курсор рисуется на 1000 пикселей выше TextFormField.

Пример
My TextFormField code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HeliosFormTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const HeliosFormTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.labelTextOnError,
    required this.validityCriteria,
    this.keyboardType,
    this.obscureText = false,
    this.clearOnError = true,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String labelText;
  final String labelTextOnError;
  final bool Function(String?) validityCriteria;
  final bool obscureText;
  final bool clearOnError;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;

  @override
  State<HeliosFormTextField> createState() => _HeliosFormTextFieldState();
}

class _HeliosFormTextFieldState extends State<HeliosFormTextField> {
  TextFieldStatus status = TextFieldStatus.none;
  ///Can change behaviour of the widget only if [widget.obscureText] is true
  bool obscureSymbols = true;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.065,),
      child: TextFormField(
            cursorErrorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            obscureText: widget.obscureText ? obscureSymbols : false,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .bodyMedium
                ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: status == TextFieldStatus.error ? widget.labelTextOnError : widget.labelText, 
              labelStyle: status == TextFieldStatus.error ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(color: Colors.red) : Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium ,
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)), borderSide: BorderSide.none),
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
              errorStyle: const TextStyle(
                height: 0,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 1000), //If i were to put double.infinity instead 1000 the exception would trigger
              suffixIcon: widget.obscureText ? 
                 IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(obscureSymbols ? Icons.visibility_rounded : Icons.visibility_off_rounded),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    obscureSymbols = !obscureSymbols;
                  }),
              )
              : null,    
            ),
            controller: widget.controller,
            validator: (value) {
              if (!widget.validityCriteria(value)) {
                if (status != TextFieldStatus.error) {
                  setState(() {
                    status = TextFieldStatus.error;
                  });
                  if (widget.clearOnError) widget.controller.clear();
                }
                return '';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (status == TextFieldStatus.error &&
                  widget.validityCriteria(value)) {
                setState(() {
                  status = TextFieldStatus.none;
                });
              }
            },
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum TextFieldStatus {
  none,
  error,
  selected,
}


Really hoping for your help
